# list of built-in aggregate and transform primitives

Tags: featuretools

First, I LOVE featuretools.  It has made my work so much easier and more efficient. One quick question: I was just looking for a full list of non-custom agg & trans primitives, but couldn't seem to find it. Do I just take the list of methods in the API and substitute lowercase (and underscore between) for capitals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `featuretools.list_primitives()`, it returns a dataframe of all the names of the primitives. The strings in the "name" column can be provided to `ft.dfs`

```py
>>> import featuretools as ft   
>>> ft.list_primitives()
                               name         type                                        description
0                      percent_true  aggregation           Determines the percent of `True` values.
1                              last  aggregation               Determines the last value in a list.
2                          num_true  aggregation                Counts the number of `True` values.
3                               std  aggregation  Computes the dispersion relative to the mean v...
4                        num_unique  aggregation  Determines the number of distinct values, igno...
5                               sum  aggregation     Calculates the total addition, ignoring `NaN`.
6                              skew  aggregation  Computes the extent to which a distribution di...
7                              mode  aggregation       Determines the most commonly repeated value.
8                  time_since_first  aggregation  Calculates the time elapsed since the first da...
9                               max  aggregation  Calculates the highest value, ignoring `NaN` v...
10                           median  aggregation  Determines the middlemost number in a list of ...
11                             mean  aggregation         Computes the average for a list of values.
12                  time_since_last  aggregation  Calculates the time elapsed since the last dat...
```

Additionally, you can also import and pass the primitive class directly. For example, this these two calls are equivalent.

```py
>>> from featuretools.primitives import Max, TimeSincePrevious
>>> ft.dfs(agg_primtives=[Max, TimeSincePrevious], ...)
>>> ft.dfs(agg_primtives=["max", "time_since_previous"], ...)
```

It can be helpful to import the primitive object if you need to modify a controllable parameter. For instance, to make `TimeSincePrevious` return in the units of hours (the default if seconds)

```py
>>> ft.dfs(agg_primtives=[Max, TimeSincePrevious(unit="hours")], ...)
```